# How to get dynamic type of empty interface

Tags: validation, go, go-gin

I tried to test validation of request data in go-gin framework so far I reached this code that work fine.

```
// RegisterEmailPasswordValidator it is used for validation and json marshalling
type RegisterEmailPasswordValidator struct {
    Email    string `json:"email" binding:"required,email"`
    Password string `json:"password" binding:"required,gte=6,lte=30"`
}

// Validate used in views
func (v *RegisterEmailPasswordValidator) Validate( c *gin.Context) error {
    if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(v); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

// use it like this in my controller
var validator validations.RegisterEmailPasswordValidator
err := validator.Validate(c)
```

To be DRY, I tried to add a global function to Validate responsibility for all structs. I tried to add a function with empty interface like bellow.

```
// Validate used in views
func Validate(c *gin.Context, customValidator interface{}) error {   
    if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&customValidator); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

// use it like this in my controller
var validator validations.RegisterEmailPasswordValidator
err := validations.Validate(c, &validator)
```

But it's not working when I send customValidator to ShouldBindJSON It uses empty interface not it's dynamic type.

Is there any way to use dynamic type of customValidator without mentioning it's type? I tried reflect.
Is there better way to be DRY in this situation in go?

Comment: @ILoveReflection I tried your suggestion, there's an error json: Unmarshal(non-pointer validations.RegisterEmailPassword)

Comment: I misunderstood the code. I don't see where the Validate function is used. Ignore my previous comment.

Comment: You should not send the pointer to an interface to your function. Also i guess the input to ShouldBindJson is an interface and you already have one, why pass the pointer to that interface?

Comment: @Mastisa The accepted answer is exactly what I suggested.  That said, the code in the question does not use the Validate function so I am still confused.

Comment: I don't remember your suggestion exactly but your suggestion had the error that I mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the interface as is, and not the pointer to the interface. something like this :

```
// Validate used in views
func Validate(c *gin.Context, customValidator interface{}) error {   
    if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(customValidator); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

// use it like this in my controller
var validator validations.RegisterEmailPasswordValidator
err := validations.Validate(c, &validator)
```

The reason is pointers in Go are not the same as pointers in C/C++, they keep the type and the value reference. A pointer to an interface is not a pointer to type it holds, but it's a pointer to the interface itself, the type is an interface. In `ShouldBindJSON` the function tries to get the object by reflection, but it gets the interface type and reference, not the `validator`s reference, therefore it can not do its job, since it needs a type, not an interface.

Comment: Pointers in Go *are* the same as pointers in C/C++. It's the interface values that are different.